# What data types should I use for arguments to redis-py functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, redis, byte

For example, when I use [`xack`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#redis.Redis.xack), do I need to convert each argument to bytes, or is this done automatically by the client?

```
xack(name, groupname, *ids)
```

It seems that using either a `str` or `bytes` id works, but I can't find an explanation for this in the documentation. Links to the relevant source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The source comments are a good reference to see the expected types. `str` will do most of the time, but some commands expect some other types in some arguments.

For example, see [`XCLAIM` in client.py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/client.py#L2311):

```
def xclaim(self, name, groupname, consumername, min_idle_time, message_ids,
           idle=None, time=None, retrycount=None, force=False,
           justid=False):
    """
    Changes the ownership of a pending message.
    name: name of the stream.
    groupname: name of the consumer group.
    consumername: name of a consumer that claims the message.
    min_idle_time: filter messages that were idle less than this amount of
    milliseconds
    message_ids: non-empty list or tuple of message IDs to claim
    idle: optional. Set the idle time (last time it was delivered) of the
     message in ms
    time: optional integer. This is the same as idle but instead of a
     relative amount of milliseconds, it sets the idle time to a specific
     Unix time (in milliseconds).
    retrycount: optional integer. set the retry counter to the specified
     value. This counter is incremented every time a message is delivered
     again.
    force: optional boolean, false by default. Creates the pending message
     entry in the PEL even if certain specified IDs are not already in the
     PEL assigned to a different client.
    justid: optional boolean, false by default. Return just an array of IDs
     of messages successfully claimed, without returning the actual message
```

You'll find in that file the other commands.

Redis strings are binary-safe. You can use `bytearray` as string. Here an [example on the tests](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/tests/test_commands.py#L526).

```
r.set(key, b'\xff\xf0\x00')
```

You can use `bytearray` on the key as well.

Comment: But can I use `str`and `bytes` interchangeably?

Comment: Yeap, expanded answer, see at the end